# How does a computer know that a two's complement number is negative?

Tags: binary

For example, 10000001 is -127 in Two's Complement, but it's also equal to 129. How do I or a computer know which number it's referring to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How do I or a computer know which number it's referring to?

It depends on whether the given number is `signed` or `unsigned`.

**Signed**

Signed values can be positive or negative. Computers use the first bit to indicate this. If the first bit is `1`, the number is negative. If the first bit is `0`, the number is positive. To determine the value of the number, the other 7 bits are used.

Hence for a signed `1000 0001`, it will mean `-1`

**Unsigned**

Unsigned values will only be positive. Since there is no indication needed for whether the number is positive or negative, all 8 bits will be used to determine the value of the number.

For an unsigned `1000 0001`, it will mean `129`

Comment: 1000 0001 is equal to -127, not -1

Comment: _first bit_ is a bit confusing, since both sides have 1 in them. Consider using the MSB and LSB terms.

Answer (score 3):

From your question, I deduce you already know you are dealing with a signed integer. So, your real question is: how do we convert a two's complement representation to a decimal number?

For demonstration purposes, I will be using 4-bit integers.
A two's complement number system encodes positive and negative numbers in a binary number representation. The weight of each bit is a power of two, except for the most significant bit (leftmost bit), whose weight is the **negative** of the corresponding power of two.

Example: Let's convert these two's complement numbers: 1110,0111,1001. 
 
1110= -2<sup>3</sup> + 2<sup>2</sup> + 2<sup>1</sup> + 0*2<sup>0</sup> = -2 
0111= -2<sup>3</sup>*0 + 2<sup>2</sup> + 2<sup>1</sup> + 2<sup>0</sup> = 7 
1001= -2<sup>3</sup> + 0*2<sup>2</sup> + 0*2<sup>1</sup> + 2<sup>0</sup> = -7

Remark: The leftmost bit gives you the sign of the number. That's, if it's "0", then the number is positive; if not, then it's negative.

So, to come back to the example you gave:
10000001 = -2<sup>7</sup> + 0 + 0 + 0 + 0 + 0 + 0 + 1= -127 (and not 129)

So, how do you represent 129 in two's complement?

To represent 129 in two's complement, you need more than 8 bits, since an additional bit is needed for the computer to know the number is positive. Not clear? Let's assume we are in a 16-bit system, here is how -127 and 129 would be stored: 
-127= 10000001  
  129= 00000000 10000001  (The leftmost bit being 0 implies the number is positive)

In case you still doubt whether or not 129 can be represented using 8 bits in two's complement: Recall that on an n-bit system, the values that can be represented in two's complement lie in the interval [-2<sup>n-1</sup>,2<sup>n-1</sup>-1].
Here, n=8 bits. Thus, the interval is [-128,127], which clearly shows that 129 is out of range.

Source:  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two's_complement

Answer (score 0):

For signed integer 8 bit representations, [the most significant bit represents the sign](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signed_number_representations#Signed_magnitude_representation). Hence, you have 7 bits to represent the value itself. For unsigned integer  8 bit representations, all 8 bits are used to represent the value, as the numbers in this representation are already assumed to be positive.